# Do we need to transfer docker-compose.yml to Production server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm pretty new to docker and docker compose. I have managed to build my image and push it to Docker Hub. The app I built is simple and consists of 2 images `php7-apache` and `mysql` offical images. All declared in `docker-compose.yml`.

I informed my team to pull the image I built from my Docker Hub repository using `docker pull ...` and start it using `docker run -d ...`. But when we run `docker ps` in the production server, only 1 process is running but no MySQL.

Usually, when I run locally using `docker-compose up` I get this in the terminal:
`Creating network "myntrelease_default" with the default driver
Creating myntrelease_mysql_1
Creating myntrelease_laravel_1`

I can then access the MySql using `docker-compose exec mysql bash` and tweak some tables there. So far so good.

Question is how can I use `docker-compose.yml` in the production server when it's not available because its in the image itself?

Comment: Please rephrase your questions as its not clear what exactly is the problem. More importantly provide a working example of your docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you need the docker-compose.yml in the production environment.

Explanation: Every image is independent. Since your image is independent of MySQL image (at least that's what I understand from your questions), and docker-compose.yml defines the relationship between the two (eg. how MySQL is accessible in the php7-apache image), then you definitely need the docker-compose.yml in production. Even if you only have a single image its usually good to use docker-compose.yml so that settings and configuration like volume mounts, ports etc. can be clearly defined.

Comment: Understood. But why I haven't seen an article or blog stating I need to upload my current `docker-compose.yml` file to production server? Can you point me to a good page?

Comment: See: https://blog.codeship.com/orchestrate-containers-for-development-with-docker-compose/ and https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Comment: Why did you have to include the getting started link? See no docker-compose there. Anyway, it looks like I need to have each server a particular `docker-compose.yml` according to the first link ;)